# How to Deploy Swift iOS Apps made with XCODE 6-beta and TestFlight

Tags: iphone, deployment, testflight, xcode6

I understand Swift is a new language and I also understand what Beta means but still it is possible and necessary to test deploy newly creates apps on the phone without updating it to iOS8.

However when I tried to use the TestFlight service, as I have done in the past (I know Apple has acquired the company), all works great until TestFlight tries to install the app on the phone. At that time one receives an error message ..."cannot be installed at this time" ...

Does anybody have an idea how I can make TestFlight work or have a viable alternative so I can test my app on the phone of somebody remote.

Any insight is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export the IPA as you normally would, making sure that you use your AdHoc provisioning profile for the release (in the build settings).

Then here's the workaround to get it to work with testflight.

1. Open a terminal and go to the directory where the IPA lives
2. `ditto -xk myapp.ipa /tmp/myapp`
3. `ditto -ck --norsrc /tmp/myapp ./myapp-after.ipa`
4. `rm -rf /tmp/myapp`

Upload myapp-after.ipa as your TestFlight build.

Comment: Thanks! That worked great. Would you mind to explain what the commands are doing. I suppose it has to do with the BETA state?